Using Mathematicas video frame insertion for tachistoscopic expositions
Has someone used in private or public research Mathematicas facilities to insert single or multiple frames into a video for embedding "tachistoskopic" material into a video of on the outside other content?
Considering the research of Otto Pötzl on "Trauminduktion durch tachistoskopische Bildexposition"
Biographie Pötzl
original article
one might experiment to implant specific dream content into one's own (or others) dreams. Has anyone tried this already?

Update
I didn't even notice VideoInsert in the documentation until now, which does exactly what we want:
v = Video["ExampleData/bullfinch.mkv"];
insert = ConstantVideo[singleFrame, 0.5];
VideoInsert[v, 5 -> insert]


Original Post
For a single frame
We first start by splitting our original video where we want to insert the new frame. Here I use the documentation example of a bird singing or something:
v = Video["ExampleData/bullfinch.mkv"];
{before, after} = VideoSplit[v, 5];

We then create a ConstantVideo with whatever duration you want the frame to show:
singleFrame = Import["ExampleData/sample.heic"]
insert = ConstantVideo[singleFrame, 0.5];

Then VideoJoin:
VideoJoin[before, insert, after]


For a multiple frame video it's simpler, just define insert as the video you want to insert into the original video.
